# How to embed braces inside an `\ensuremath` environment inside a `\newglossaryentry`?

Tags: braces, glossaries-extra

Running `pdflatex` on the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{injective}{name={\ensuremath{X\overset{1:1}{\rightarrow}Y}},description={injective function}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsadd{injective}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

produces the following compilation error:

```
! Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 ...arrow}Y}},description={injective function}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\overset` is not robust so it fails when writing to file. Try

```
...X\protect\overset...
```

BTW I'd probably use `amsmath` and `\xrightarrow{1{:}1}` instead of the `\overset` construction